# visual studio enterprise - load testing - how to log in to ADFS within coded test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, load-testing, visual-studio-2015, adfs

I have recorded a performance test using a perf/load test project in Visual Studio as per these instructions from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn250793.aspx.  I then turned it into a coded test by clicking "Generate Code".

Now I am trying to run the test, but it doesn't recognise some of the code it's written, like

```
request6Body.FormPostParameters.Add("AuthMethod", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.AuthMethod"].ToString());
```

(In this case it says there's no context parameter called "$HIDDEN1.AuthMethod").

I know that this is probably because the ADFS screen doesn't return the same headers etc. each time, but has anyone written code to get around this, and if so, how's it done?

Thanks!

Comment: This commonly means that something earlier in the test failed, so a different response was sent; perhaps an error page. This different page does not contain the wanted hidden parameters.

Answer (score -1):

For our tests, I developed a method which allows to use a simulated/fake login, which allows you to use the App without ADFS and without redirections. Of course, this should be disabled in production. Next time you record the test, you start straight away with the fake login.

We use ASP.NET MVC so I can only show you how that works in ASP.NET MVC.

#### Controller Action

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Impersonate([Bind(Prefix = "id")]string email)
    {
        Impersonalisator.ImpersonateByEMail(email, Request);
        return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { action = string.Empty, controller = string.Empty });
    }
```

(So you can execute: /Home/Impersonate/demouser@example.com

#### Impersonalisator.ImpersonateByEMail

```
    public static void ImpersonateByEMail(string email, HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        // you don't need this if clause, or you introduce this appsetting in your web.config
        if ("true" == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableImpersonate"])
        {
            var impersonatedIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("ApplicationCookie");

            impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email));

            // Add other claims you might need

            var owinContext = request.GetOwinContext();
            owinContext.Authentication.SignOut("ApplicationCookie");
            owinContext.Authentication.SignIn(impersonatedIdentity);
        }
    }
```

You can start logged in without going over ADFS, you don't want to have ADFS or other Authentication services in your tests anyway, e.g. in load tests you might "attack" those services and cause failures etc.